# How can I modify the internal swarm load balancer IP address?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm in a cluster of machines and my use case is deploying several standalone containers that need to be connected which have static IP configurations, so I created an overlay to connect all the nodes of the swarm. I don't use/want to use anything related to docker SERVICES nor its replication in my docker swarm, it's not a real word scenario it's a test one.

The problem is when I deploy a container to a certain host a the swarm load balancer is created with a certain IP address which is random and I need it to be static because I can't change the configurations of the containers I want to deploy. I already searched how can I remove this load balancer, because as far as I'm concerned it's only used for external traffic coming into the swarm services/containers and they are not useful for my use case.

A solution would be deploy a dummy container and check which IP was assigned to the swarm load balancers in each node and then adjust the configuration files of the containers I want to deploy, but this approach does not scale well and it's a workaround of the actual problem. My problems started when randomly my containers couldn't start giving `docker: Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded.` where I could not identify it's reason to happen and then inferred it was because these load balancers where using the same IP adress I wanted to use in my containers.

My question is how can I statically define the IP of these load balancers or remove them completely for every node? Thank you for your time.
[Docker Swarm Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvAke.png) Here is the output of `docker inspect network <my-overlay-network>`

```
    "Name": "my-network",

    "Id": "mo8rcf8ozr05qrnuqh64wamhs",
    "Created": "2020-11-16T01:59:20.100290182Z",
    "Scope": "swarm",
    "Driver": "overlay",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "10.0.1.0/24",
                "Gateway": "10.0.1.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "95b8e9c3ab5f9870987c4077ce264b96a810dad573a7fa2de485dd6f4b50f307": {
            "Name": "unruffled_haslett",
            "EndpointID": "422d83efd66ae36dd10ab0b1eb1a70763ccef6789352b06b8eb3ec8bca48410f",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:0c",
            "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.12/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "lb-my-network": {
            "Name": "my-network-endpoint",
            "EndpointID": "192ffaa13b7d7cfd36c4751f87c3d08dc65e66e97c0a134dfa302f55f77dcef3",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:08",
            "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.8/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
```

`

Comment: The question is why are using swarm when you have standalone containers? and when you say you want to set a static IP to a container, then what do you do when a swarm SERVICE is replicated and creates more than one container?

I am just trying to say that maybe using docker swarm is the problem.

Finally, I would say that the host machine needs to forward each static ip address you have to a `nodeport` of each `service` and then this becomes an `iptables` problem not a docker swarm one.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I don't want to use anything related to services or replicate them in swarm. My objective here is I have a cluster of machines and I need to setup  up a test to run a couple hundreds of containers and then I have a module that inject latency inside the docker swarm. It only works on docker swarm. I don't have any published ports or anything related to exterior communication.  That's why I used it, among other reasons.

Comment: I understand that you don't want to replicate but services created by swarm work under the assumption that you can. Also when deploying a new image to a service using swarm (and depending on ur configuration) then the service might have two containers online for a brief period. For all above reasons setting static IPs is a bad idea and im not sure is even possible.

Comment: To point you to a different direction, you said that you don't have any published port so I assume that the services in the swarm communicate with each other, in which case why dont you use the service_name as an hostname instead of setting static IPs

Comment: Thank you for your help, while reading all documentation on docker swarm and it's architecture I came up with a way to avoid my problem, which was I had 100+ containers running across a swarm cluster of 16 machines. In these machines the static configuration accidently collided with the internal load ballancer IP. My solution was to use a wider subnet mask which allowed me to avoid collisions. Althouth not the ideal solution will work great. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I just use a wider subnet mask of /16 instead of /24. Which allowed me to have more IP addresses and thus avoiding collisions with the Internal load balancers.